# Error 0X8007003B: An unexpected network error has occurred

Tags: networking, ntfs, network-shares, windows-server-2012, windows-server

When trying to transfer files to network drives, we are experiencing the same error at random times. 0x8007003B error.

[image]

This started only about three days ago and is been affecting several users. How/ where to start troubleshooting this kind of issue?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of network drive?

Comment: network shared drives

Comment: Is it a nas or another PC?

Comment: This is a Buffalo TeraStation model: WS5400R1604 running Windows 2012

Comment: If you have AV software, turn it off and see if it still does it. Also try turning of any firewall, do these one at a time to see if it either one causing the issue, there is a software updater for that model on this page>>>>>>>>https://www.buffalotech.com/support/downloads/terastation-5000n-wss-rackmount

Comment: See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/297859/423274). It reads: _" It turns out that the combination of having 802.1x configured (through GPO) and having [antivirus] configured to scan network drives when uploading large files to a DFS share"_.